# Cannot access values from JSON Object which is in unusal form

Tags: jquery, json

I have below JSON text format

```
[
{"fields": {"Num": 34, "Univ": "TUni"}, "pk": 1, "model": "app.unbased"}, 
{"fields": {"Num": 10, "Univ": "VTU"}, "pk": 1, "model": "app.unbased"}
]
```

I tried to access fields value of Num of the first item using Jquery, but couldn't get it.
I have already gone through other questions related to JSON but no use as this form is unusual.

I tried below in the success function

```
success: function (json) {
            $('#PieStats').html(json.message);
            var data_json = $.parseJSON(json.message);
            alert(typeof(json.message)); // Output : string
            alert(data_json[0][0]); // Output : Undefined
            alert(typeof (json) + ' ' + typeof (data_json));  // Output : object object
            $('.ajaxProgress').hide();
        }
```

I have also tried using data_json['fields'][0][0] and other possible ways - doesn't work

What am I missing ?

Comment: `data_json[0].fields.Num` should do it

Comment: You are missing that only the top level structure is an array.

Comment: Many thanks Wolff! How to access the json when we are not sure of field name ?

Comment: But I don't see any key named "message" in your JSON text format. Again, you should go like: `var data_json = $.parseJSON(json);`. After that, try `console.log(data_json);` to see the data structure fetched.

Comment: @user3128771 use a loop to get all the object keys. You should start by reading provided dupe link, there is a part in answer explaining it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

```
var jsonString = '[\
{"fields": {"Num": 34, "Univ": "TUni"}, "pk": 1, "model": "app.unbased"}, \
{"fields": {"Num": 10, "Univ": "VTU"}, "pk": 1, "model": "app.unbased"}\
]';
var dataObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(dataObject[0].fields.Num);
```

Comment: In case if we are not sure of fields (Num and Univ in this case), how to access those values ?

Comment: `for(var i in dataObject){ if(dataObject.hasOwnProperty(i)){ console.log(i," ->", dataObject[i]); } }`

Comment: Your code gives 0 and 1 only. I would like to see 34,TUvi,10,VTU  (Values)

Answer (score 0):

data_json[0].fields.Num is what you are looking for. Each element in the array is an object and that is why you get undefined for data_json[0][0]

Comment: Thanks a lot Sasikanth! How to access the json when we are not sure of field name (in this case Num) ?